# Combine a JS to conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

JS newbie here.  I have a landing page with two options - once and regular (two buttons).  we have to include a script to the page, but can't have both firing and rather need it to be conditional.

The scripts are like this:

```
    <!-- Regular Donation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.adalyserTracker("trackEvent", "lce3", {value: 0.00, a4:"Regular"}, true);
</script>

<!-- One-off Donation -->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.adalyserTracker("trackEvent", "lce3", {value: 0.00, a4:"Once"}, true);
</script>
```

Any ninjas out there who can help combine those quickly to one (e.g. if id on the button = once, use 'Once', if Id on the button = regular, use 'Regular')

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should have done some research, which would have led to pages such as https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: oh wow you're right geez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and pass the event as the `sender.` Use the `sender` to get the element id of the button that was clicked. Place the id value into the call to `window.adalyserTracker.`

```js
// this is not a built-in method for 'window' so I am creating a placeholder
window.adalyserTracker = function(p1,p2,p3,p4) {
  // do your work here
  console.log(p1);
  console.log(p2);
  console.log(p3);
  console.log(p4);
}

// create click events for the buttons. these events call the apply function
document.getElementById('Once').addEventListener('click', function(e) { apply(e); });
document.getElementById('Regular').addEventListener('click', function(e) { apply(e); });

function apply(sender) {
  var id = sender.target.id; // get the id of the button clicked
  window.adalyserTracker("trackEvent", "lce3", {value: 0.00, a4:id}, true);
  // a4:id is where you use the id to pass the appropriate value
}
```

```html
<button id="Once" class="btn">Once</button>
<button id="Regular" class="btn">Regular</button>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think this should do it.